# Which Stack Exchange site should I use to ask DMV related question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I just sold my car and I had some DMV paperwork related questions. Which Stack Exchange website should I use to ask these questions?

Comment: Why not just call... the DMV?

Comment: @won't: Do not wan to deal with them

Comment: You have to.  Do you think that paperwork is going to be processed by the keebler elves?  Submit yourself to the machine.

Comment: I don't think that any SE site has an automatic three-hour delay while you wait in a queue, so DMV questions cannot be handled correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Personal Finance and Money**](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/58118/private-car-sale)

As this is a paperwork related question regarding the DMV, it would be more [on-topic](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/58118/32662) in the Money site of SE.

I would not think this in it's current state and meaning, would be on-topic on the Motor Vehicle Repair site, as it's description from the help-center says:

> Motor Vehicles Stack Exchange is for mechanics and DIY-enthusiast
>   owners of cars, trucks, and motorcycles.
>
> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and
>   their accessories, internal combustion engines, even in applications
>   other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or
>   engine accessories.

Comment: Agreed - motor vehicles is very much the mechanics end, not anything to do with finance!

Answer (score 2):

The [Personal Finance and Money Stack Exchange](https://money.stackexchange.com/) seems to have [similar questions](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=dmv) to what you are describing, but as always please read their Help before deciding whether your question appears to be on-topic for them.

I came to this conclusion using a [Google Search with terms "dmv car sale stack exchange"](http://www.google.com/search?q=dmv%20car%20sale%20stack%20exchange).

The [Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair (Beta) Stack Exchange](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) which also shows up in those results seems less likely.